# Create a local branch and push to remote with the earlier two commits from my master branch

Tags: git, github

I have a typical problem which is like the following:

1) I was working on an Issue X, I made 2 commits for that issue, but I was stuck in between and did not push the changes to my remote repo.

My git status on master branch says that

Your branch is ahead by 2 commits.

2) I am now assigned a new task and I want to push the 2 commits which I did in the master branch in a local branch which I would create now.

I tried achieving the same as :
1) git log (on master and noted the commit nos lets call them 1111(for commit 1, old commit) and 2222(for commit 2, newest commit)
2) git checkout -b my_local_branch
3) git cherry-pick 1111

Now, there are conflicts. Can someone tell me what is it that I should do. Maybe apply the newest commit because I feel that my local branch does not have those commits (I might be wrong), because when I do

git status (on my local_branch), I don't see that my branch is ahead of any commit.

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I guess this will work.

On your master branch, run `git branch -b my-local`. Check that your commit 1111 and 2222 are O.K.

Go back to master branch: `git checkout master`.

Run `git rebase -i`, and delete commit 1111 and 2222.

Now master branch got rid of 1111 and 2222, you can start your new task. (And commmit 1111 and 2222 are in your my-local branch.)